# Using `on` argument in combination with CJ

Tags: r, data.table

I want to derive summary statistics for a subset of more than one variables of different lengths.
Trying to use the `on` Argument in `data.table` in combination with `CJ` I got a solution with much more typing work than using keyed variables. Is there any better solution for this task?

```
require(data.table) 
dt <- CJ(year = 2015:2016, class = 1:4, age = 15:20)
set.seed(1)
dt[, var := rnorm(48)]
dt[CJ(class = 2:3, age = 15:17),
      list(med = median(var)), on = c("class", "age"),
      keyby = .(age, year, class)]

##     age year class        med
##  1:  15 2015     2  0.4874291
##  2:  15 2015     3 -0.6212406
##  3:  15 2016     2  1.3586796
##  4:  15 2016     3 -0.3942900
##  5:  16 2015     2  0.7383247
##  6:  16 2015     3 -2.2146999
##  7:  16 2016     2 -0.1027877
##  8:  16 2016     3 -0.0593134
##  9:  17 2015     2  0.5757814
## 10:  17 2015     3  1.1249309
## 11:  17 2016     2  0.3876716
## 12:  17 2016     3  1.1000254

##### keyed version -- less typing work
setkey(dt, class, age)
dt[CJ(2:3, 15:17), list(med = median(var)),
   keyby = .(age, year, class)]

##### same result as above
```

Comment: The point of using `on` is to make your code more clear, which the "more typing" version is. You could trim it down by doing `CJ(2:3, 15:17)` and then `on = c(class = "V1", age = "V2")`.

Comment: @MichaelChirico I guess that's a matter of style. I'd keep `on=` short but put the names explicitly in CJ. Or maybe I'd not do a join, since the OP is just filtering, not using `by=.EACHI`

Comment: @Frank I agree -- just giving OP options :)

Comment: Ok :) Fwiw, here's what I'd do: `dt[ class %in% 2:3 & age %in% 15:17, .(med = median(var)), keyby=.(age, year, class) ]` or maybe `dt[, .(med = median(var)), keyby=.(age, year, class) ][ class %in% 2:3 & age %in% 15:17 ]`

Comment: @nachti You have shown the wrong output, sorted age, class, year instead of age, year, class. Or something like that ... anyway, it's quite different from what I see running your code.

Comment: @Konrad: Thanks for inserting the missing first line; @Frank: The key was ok, but med values were mixed up somhow - I updated the post. And of course I want to use binary search -- therefore I didn't use `class %in% 2:3 & age %in% 15:17` and so on.

Comment: @Frank: In this case vector search seems to be faster than binary search -- see last section of https://github.com/nachti/datatable_test/blob/master/datatable_reports.R

Comment: I think the example is too small to draw any conclusions from its benchmark. Btw, there is a feature request for extending binary search to apply to the version I wrote: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1453 In the meantime, you can chain it `dt[ class %in% 2:3 ][ age %in% 15:17 ]` which will use binary search (which is automatically triggered for these cases, see https://rawgit.com/wiki/Rdatatable/data.table/vignettes/datatable-secondary-indices-and-auto-indexing.html ). Anyway, I invited you to an SO chat room in case there's more to discuss.